# Referencing columns using column headers of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe "A":

```
             1   2   3
Date                  
1971-01-04  46  47   9
1971-01-05  95  58   6
1971-01-06  30  52  85
```

and the following empty dataframe "B", with the same row indices as "A", and multi-index columns:

```
              1         
level_1       1         2         3
Date                               
1971-01-04  
1971-01-05  
1971-01-06
```

I'm trying to fill "B" using either of the two levels of the column headers to identify the column of "A" to get the data from.

So, when using the first column headers level [1, 1, 1], this is the expected output:

```
1971-01-04  46  46  46
1971-01-05  95  95  95
1971-01-06  30  30  30
```

and this is the expected output when using the second column headers level [1, 2, 3]:

```
1971-01-04  46  47   9
1971-01-05  95  58   6
1971-01-06  30  52  85
```

I could iterate through columns but I guess there's a better way.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you can just index directly into `A` without having to create `B` at all

```
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['1971-01-04', '1971-01-05', '1971-01-06'],
    1: [46, 95, 30],
    2: [47, 58, 52],
    3: [9, 6, 85],
})

A = A.set_index('Date')


print(A[[1,1,1]])
#              1   1   1
# Date                  
# 1971-01-04  46  46  46
# 1971-01-05  95  95  95
# 1971-01-06  30  30  30

print(A[[1,2,3]])
#              1   2   3
# Date                  
# 1971-01-04  46  47   9
# 1971-01-05  95  58   6
# 1971-01-06  30  52  85


#here's how you could "reset" the column names
print(A[[2,2,3]].set_axis(range(3), axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works fine with the sample dataframes. Unfortunately, the real dataframes are much larger so I can't just index directly into "A"; that's the reason why I would like to index using column headers from "B"

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I still don't understand since indexing with a list of column names like in my answer above should be fast even on huge tables. Maybe this is an XY problem? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What final goal are you trying to accomplish, or what's your immediate issue you're working around?

Comment: Thank you for your help! The issue is not the time to execute the command, but the time to manually input the column names in the indexing function (A[[1,2,3.......]]. I guess I could get the column names list and put it in the indexing function, but if I try A.columns.levels I get ([['1'], ['1', '2', '3']]) whilst I would need ([['1', '1', '1'], ['1', '2', '3']])

Comment: I think I can use list(A.columns.get_level_values(0)) and list(A.columns.get_level_values(1))